# Using Digest Auth in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Hello im working on prototype which is using digest authentication to other server in meteor. Can any body please help me how to do this? I have tried and searched all threads discussion about this using nodejs. Can anybody please help me with the help of meteor code?

```
   var options = {
   host: 'http://some-api-link/',
   port: 3000,
   path: '/path',
   // authentication headers
   headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(username + ':' + passw).toString('base64')
   }   
};

//this is the call
request = http.get(options, function(res){
   var body = "";
   res.on('data', function(data) {
      body += data;
   });
   res.on('end', function() {
      console.log(body);
   })
   res.on('error', function(e) {
      console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
   });
});
```

Comment: Can you show what you have done? No code, no help.

Comment: @Florent im doing somethng like this. May be im wrong coz im new to Meteor. But please give me a working example

Comment: Any working example that can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `http` package

In your console:

```
meteor add http
```

Then you can do:

```
var result = HTTP.get( "http://some-api-link/path",
                       {auth: 'username:password',
                        params: {some_param: 'some value'}});

console.log(result.content); //or result.data depending on what you want
```

Full docs on what you can do/how are here: http://docs.meteor.com/#http_call